# Firestore Where array-contains, ignore if empty

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On each of my documents, I have an array called `nameIndexes` that is an array of keywords, something like:

```
["cat", "christmas", "tree", "topper", "decoration"]
```

I then have an array of search terms, which I look through an perform a where query on.  What I am finding though is that is someone searches for something that doesn't exist in the array, the results are empty.

My code that searches is like so:

```
this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('designs').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection('designs');
try {
  searchArray.forEach(a => {
    this.ref = this.designCollection.where("nameIndexes", "array-contains", a)
  })
  const designs = await this.ref.get();
  designs.forEach(doc => {
    let design = doc.data();
    design.id = doc.id;
    d.push(design)
  })
} catch (e) {
  message.error(e.message)
}
```

---

Some examples:

**Scenario 1**

Search Terms are `["horse", "cat"]`

It returns the document that where the nameIndexes is `["cat", "christmas", "tree", "topper", "decoration"]`

**Scenario 2**

Search Terms are `["cat", "horse"]`

No results are found

---

What I'm assuming here is that in scenario 1, it finds no horse in the array, so moves on to cat and returns the results.  In scenario 2, it finds cat, moves onto horse, can't find it so just returns nothing.

Is there a way to make it so that returns all results where the query matches?   The only way I can think of doing this is by performing separate where queries and then pushing all the results to an array, however if there are multiple search terms, this is going to take a while and add load to my Firestore instance

Comment: I think this is not possible at the moment, also struggling with this...